How to detect an existing state of bar chart
In my application, I have created an bar chart.
when I perform zoom over data with mouse, proper datazoom event is triggered.
to restore the datazoom event, I should know the datazoom event is happened.
is there any way that I could find a datazoom event is in place with my bar chart ?

https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/event/# - chart.on('click', 'dataZoom', function () {...});

You can get the current option with getOption and examine the dataZoom.
Example:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  dataZoom: {},
  series: [
    {
      data: [120, 200, 150, 80, 70, 110, 130],
      type: 'bar'
    }
  ]
};


setTimeout(function() {
  const dataZoom = myChart.getOption().dataZoom[0];
  console.log("start absolute: " + dataZoom.startValue + " (" + dataZoom.start + " %)");
  console.log("end absolute: " + dataZoom.endValue + " (" + dataZoom.end + " %)");
}, 4000);

